# First person shooter for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, games

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 Laptop with 8GB RAM and Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU 2020M @ 2.40GHz Processor. For this system I am looking for an *easy to install* first person shooter. It does not have to have the latest graphics, but an easy-to-install game with fullscreen mode, with a fluid gameplay possible.

Must have:

- Easy to install, best with `apt-get install`
- Fullscreen
- Free

Other info:

- Does not have to be multiplayer

Comment: Please ask for software recommendations over on [SoftwareRecs.SE]. They're usually off topic here if they're as broad as yours.

Answer (score 4):

#### For Ubuntu >= 16.04

In a terminal type

```
ubuntu-software --search "first person shooter"
```

for a list of free games that come with Ubuntu. Choose <kbd>install</kbd> of those you like.

#### For Ubuntu 14.04

search the Ubuntu Software Center:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Quake Arena 1,2,3 and Assault Cube . You can find those on the app store or softare-center